# resize2fs get status after ssh connection interrupted

Tags: linux, ssh, command-line-interface, filesystems

I lost SSH connection after I executed a `resize2fs` command on my drive /dev/md0.

Is there a way, now that I've restablished a connection, to check if the resize2fs is still running? And the status?

Comment: FYI:  Use [GNU screen](http://www.gnu.org/software/screen/) for things like this!

Comment: Yea, learning the hard way.. :(

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are plenty of ways to check if a process is running. An old school `ps aux | grep resize2fs` would do the trick, just as well as `pgrep -l resize2fs`. You could also use `top` or `htop` and search for the process.

There is a good chance that `resize2fs` aborted when your session got disconnected. If that is a concern, run it from within `screen` next time (as already suggested).

Regarding the progress, there is unfortunately no easy way to check. If you are doing an **offline** resize, then you might have some luck running `dumpe2fs -h /dev/md0` and see if the block counters are moving. I wouldn't expect those to change until everything is finished though. If you were growing the system **online**, then it is easier. Just check how much free space there is on the mount point. The free space would normally constantly grow for an online resize.

Comment: Thanks! I ended up re-running the command under GNU screen. It said it could not be run because the filesystem was already ad the block edge of the drive. I also mountd it to make sure, everything looks good!